# Parse with Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, parse-platform

I am using Parse (http://parse.com) inside a Meteor Application (http://meteor.com)

I am trying to query my Parse Database from the server side, and everything is fine until I get to the query.

I get the following error:

**[TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of undefined]**

This is what my code looks like: [I have even tried query.find()]

```
var VITxUser = Parse.Object.extend("VITxMaster");
var query = new Parse.Query(VITxUser);
query.equalTo("fbid", "1231212");
//no errors till here
query.first({
          success: function(object) {
            if (!object){
                //insert the user
                var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("VITxMaster");
                var gameScore = new GameScore();
                gameScore.set("fbid", profile.id);
                gameScore.set("registrationNumber", "12DEV0000");
                gameScore.set("VITevents", "true");
                gameScore.save(null, {
                  success: function(gameScore) {
                    // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
                    alert('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id + 'and fbid: ' + profile.id);
                  },
                  error: function(gameScore, error) {
                    // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                    alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
                  }
                });
            }
            else{
                console.log("found object");
                console.log(object.get("registrationNumber"));
            }

          }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reference to `getItem` in your code. I suspect however that the issue is due to meteor's variable scoping. Basically in Meteor each file is variable scoped. So you if you had two files `file1.js` and `file2.js` they would be wrapped around in a `function(){..}`.

You would need to remove the variable scoping by not using `var` to define your variables. Particularly the one's you want to be accessible globally (in other files)

Comment: I agree, there is no getItem in my code. But the error comes just before the line "query.find()" so i guess it's somehow attached to that. Plus i tried removing "var" from my code, still the same error.

Comment: It must be from the parse library, similarly you would have to make the variable containing getItem in there publicly accessible by removing `var` too. It's a bit tedious at the moment but it should get easier when the linker branch of meteor is complete